# How to require a class when building a ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am creating a gem, here is my structure :

```
lib/
  | myapp.rb
  | myapp/
      | version.rb
      | configuration.rb
      | use_cases/
      |   base_use_case.rb
      |   entity1/
      |     show_entity.rb
spec/
myapp.gemspec
```

I would like to make my class ShowEntity inherit from BaseUseCase.

```
module MyApp::UseCases::Entity1
  class ShowEntity < BaseUseCase
  end
end
```

But I get the following error

```
in `<module:Entity1>': uninitialized constant MyApp::UseCases::Entity1::BaseUseCase (NameError)
```

In myapp.rb I required each classes but I still get the error.

This is the first time I try to really understand how modules and classes work together and to require them inside a gem project, so any help or explanations on why I get that error will be great.

Comment: it seems your class BaseUseCase is `MyApp::UseCases::BaseUseCase` and not `MyApp::UseCases::Entity1::BaseUseCase`

Comment: try `::` before `BaseUseCase` or `MyApp::UseCases::BaseUseCase`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
module MyApp::UseCases::Entity1
  class ShowEntity < BaseUseCase
  end
end
```

Ruby will first look for `BaseUseCase` in the current module, `MyApp::UseCases::Entity1`. Assuming this class is defined under `MyApp::UseCases` to match your file structure, it won’t be found there. Ruby then looks in the enclosing scope to try to find the class. However, since you’ve used the double colon syntax, the enclosing scope is the top–level, *not* `MyApp::UseCases` as you may be expecting. Ruby “jumps over” all the namespaces in the statement `module MyApp::UseCases::Entity1`.

If instead you defined the class like this it should work:

```
module MyApp::UseCases
  module Entity1
    class ShowEntity < BaseUseCase
    end
  end
end
```

Here, when `BaseUseCase` isn’t found in the current scope the enclosing scope searched is `MyApp::UseCases`. Ruby steps back a single `module` statement at a time, and since there is now a separate declaration for `Entity1`, the next scope is `MyApp::UseCases` instead of the top level. If `BaseUseCase` were defined directly under `MyApp` instead then this code wouldn’t work either, since after failing to find it under `MyApp::UseCases::Entity1` and `MyApp::UseCases` the next scope searched would be the top level.

To fix it you should break out your `module` declarations as needed as above, or explicitly define the fully namespaced name of `BaseUseCase`:

```
class ShowEntity < ::MyApp::UseCases::BaseUseCase
```